# SQL Combination of rows having specific value for all columns

Tags: sql

Data:

```
    |c1 |c2 |c3 |c4 |c5 |c6
----|---|---|---|---|---|--
r1  |1  |0  |0  |1  |0  |0
----|---|---|---|---|---|--
r2  |1  |1  |0  |0  |0  |0
----|---|---|---|---|---|--
r3  |0  |0  |1  |0  |1  |0
----|---|---|---|---|---|--
r4  |0  |1  |0  |1  |1  |1
```

I want to find row/combination of rows using SQL wherein all columns have specific value(i.e 1).

So, from the sample data we should get r4 and (r2,r3 or r1,r3) as combination.
i.e least no. of rows covering all columns.

EDIT: No. of rows would be around 10-12.
and value in 0 and 1 for all columns.
using the sum of columns we can get the first reference row covering maximum columns.
I am not able to figure out how to go about the remaining part.

A row can have column values 0 in which case another row where the column has value 1 will be picked up as a combination. So, with r4, (r3 and r2) or (r1 and r3) should be picked as a combination.
for r4 columns c1 and c3 are 0.
so r1 and r3 can be selected with r4 as combination.

Comment: Please show the code that you wrote to solve the problem.

Comment: @Fabulous see comment.

Comment: You say where "all columns have a specific value (i.e. 1)". And then you want r4 as a result, which has columns with value = 0.

Comment: This seems like the kind of problem that is a very bad fit for SQL.

Comment: @Seb All columns for a single row/combination of rows.

Comment: Column c1 and c3 have 0 as value. Please be specific about your question!

Comment: @Seb Please read the question again. A row can have column values 0 in which case another row where the column has value 1 will be picked up as a combination. So, with r4, (r3 and r2) or (r1 and r3) should be picked as a combination

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

So you want the least number of rows that in combination have value 1 in alls columns. Optimal case would be 1 row. Worst case would the same number of rows as number of columns.

I would say this is difficult (impossible) in sql alone. You can go for the row with the hightest number of value 1.

```
SELECT a.rowNumber, a.valueCount FROM (
    SELECT rowNumber, SUM(col1, col2, col3, ...) as valueCount FROM tableName; ) as a
ORDER BY a.valueCount DESC
-- LIMIT 1
```

Use the limit if you only want one row. The rest could not be done in a query - at least not without stretching sql to some absurd distance. Even then this is no easy problem to be solved. Because the row with the hightest valueCount might not be the best row to use.